# placing a taking image in a right place. Tags

Tags: android, tags

At first i have a method to create view(yes i know its wrong, but it works fine for me):

```
 public ImageView createPhotoField(final Context context,
                LinearLayout reviewsLayout, Integer id, String comment, OnClickListener a, OnClickListener b, int tag) {

            /* reviewLayout */
            LinearLayout reviewLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            reviewLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, densityToPixels(132,
                            context)));
            reviewLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            reviewLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            /* reviewEntryTopLayout */
            LinearLayout reviewEntryTopLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            reviewEntryTopLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, densityToPixels(65,
                            context)));
            reviewEntryTopLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            reviewEntryTopLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

            /* reviewsLayout */

            reviewsLayout.addView(reviewLayout);

            /* entryNumber */
            ImageView imageview = new ImageView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams entryNumberParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            imageview.setTag(tag);

            entryNumberParams.setMargins(40, 0, 0, 0);
            imageview.setLayoutParams(entryNumberParams);
            imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_bad);
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bad);
            //entryNumber.set
            imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            reviewLayout.addView(reviewEntryTopLayout);

            //reviewEntryTopLayout.addView(entryNumber);

            /* table layout */

            TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(context);
            tl.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            tl.setPadding(densityToPixels(20, context), 0, 0, 0);
            reviewEntryTopLayout.addView(tl);

            /* tableRow1 */
            TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow(context);
            tableRow1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,


                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                tl.addView(tableRow1);      
                /* textView1 */
                TextView comment_photo = new TextView(context);
                comment_photo.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                comment_photo.setText(comment);
                tableRow1.addView(imageview);
                tableRow1.addView(comment_photo);

                /* lightSeperatorLayout */
                LinearLayout lightSeperatorLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                lightSeperatorLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, densityToPixels(1,
                                context)));
                lightSeperatorLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                lightSeperatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5d5d5"));



                /* reviewEntryBottomLayout */
                LinearLayout reviewEntryBottomLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
                reviewEntryBottomLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, densityToPixels(65,
                                context)));
                reviewEntryBottomLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                reviewEntryBottomLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                reviewLayout.addView(reviewEntryBottomLayout);

                /* tableRow3 */
                TableRow tableRow3 = new TableRow(context);
                tableRow3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tableRow3.setPadding(densityToPixels(10, context),
                        densityToPixels(10, context), densityToPixels(10, context),
                        densityToPixels(10, context));

                reviewEntryBottomLayout.addView(tableRow3);

                /* editButton */
                Button editButton = new Button(context);
                TableRow.LayoutParams editButtonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        Tabl

    eRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150);
            editButtonParams.weight = 0.5f;
            editButtonParams.setMargins(15, 0, 30, 0);
            editButton.setLayoutParams(editButtonParams);
            editButton.setText("Take a photo");


            tableRow3.addView(editButton);

            /* reviewButton */
            Button reviewButton = new Button(context);
            TableRow.LayoutParams reviewButtonParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 150);
            reviewButtonParams.weight = 0.5f;
            reviewButtonParams.setMargins(30, 0, 15, 0);
            reviewButton.setLayoutParams(reviewButtonParams);
            reviewButton.setText("Gallery");


            tableRow3.addView(reviewButto

n);
        reviewLayout.addView(lightSeperatorLayout);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(a);
        reviewButton.setOnClickListener(b);


        return imageview;
    }
```

long story short: this method creates: an imageview, for a photo, a text field, and two buttons, to choose u take a photo, or u take it from gallery.

After calling this method below few times the view is created

```
image = element.createPhotoField(this, reviewsLayout,
                            Integer.parseInt(element_id), input_name, a, b,tag);
```

the **problem** is: i can't find a way to place a photo in a right place. I have heard about tags, but i dont know how to implement those. Could somebody more experienced give me a hand ?

Maybe i should use adapter for this ??

[image]

Comment: i didnt understand your problem? is it that you know the place but dont know how to code it to place image there?

Comment: i don't know how to get the right place, and how to put an image in that place.

Comment: ok. Where do you think is the right place on mobile screen?

Comment: that method creates: imageview(this is the place i want to show the photo after it is taken or chosen from gallery)

Comment: it is still not clear to me. Are you looking for any position on screen to place image?

Comment: this appears when i use that method three times. now it is more clearly i think

Comment: Yes it is clear now. In that case you are right about adapter. This is a list of details..so you will need adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your adapter is required to achieve what you need :

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youListItem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.youImageView);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

            holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
            //to display image
            holder.image.setImageDrawable(YourImageDrawable);
            return view;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    //view elements of single list item
    public ImageView image;
}
```